# Notepad++ NppFTP freezes after successful authentication

Tags: notepad++

I am attempting to use NppFTP to connect to a new CentOS 7 server and it continues to freeze without an error message

Here is the Output:
[NppFTP] Everything initialized
Connecting
[SFTP] Host key accepted
[SFTP] Successfully authenticated

However, NppFTP  still says that it is "Connecting" and I am unable to do anything. I have tried reinstalling the plugin and it still does nothing. I will say that I have used this in the past to connect to CentOS 7 servers. I have made sure that openssh-server was complete up to date on the server.

SOLUTION: See my answer below.

Comment: Looks like the question is incomplete, it seems to end in the middle of a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by opening /etc/ssh/sshd_config and modifying this line "Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" into "Subsystem sftp internal-sftp"

I do not know why this worked, but it did. If someone would like to explain this to me, that would be cool.

Comment: It may caused by large messages printed from the profile script.